# BitBucket private repo installed via SSH - is it possible to pull only certain files/directories?

Tags: npm, bitbucket, private

There is a functionality with npm where only certain files are published to the registry. This can be achieved (from my research) using .npmignore or the "files" key in package.json to exclude certain files from the package when published on the registry.

However, I am using BitBucket private repos and not publishing to the registry. Is there any method when I can have yarn/npm pull only certain files/dirs (like using .npmignore or the "files" key) or see only a sub directory as the root directory and then installing only that as though it was the root? Thanks.